# Create Active Report with version 9

Tags: xml, activereports

I need to create an ActiveReport with version 9.
I am running into some trouble. all the online documentation is from the former company that was purchased.

I need to load a Rpt file from disk to a SectionReport and pass XML data to it to hydrate it. The problem is that my xml data is created on the fly and I do not have an xml datasource to bind to. I need to pass the data to an xml object of some kind and have it hydrate the report so that I can print it. The data is not from a file. So I can not pass a schema and have it looking to a directory to load an XML schema or XML file. The only directory access is when getting the report.rpt file so that I can pass it to the SectionReport Object.

My goal is to print and email this stuff as a pdf.

Hope you all can help.

-Pete

Can someone help. It's complex job here at work.

Answer (score 0):

Pete

Not entirely sure how you would actually do what it is that you're after doing however I can point you in the direction of the correct online documentation (which is also available in formats that you can download for local consumption.

You'll find what you need [here](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/docs/)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you guys!

I have been able to get this to work however, in the details section of the report, I need to have it hydrate the section from the xml from <items><item> and It only puts the first row of data and nothing after that. this is with having 6 items in the list. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Pete,

Attached is a sample using v9 of ActiveReports that simulates what you are doing.  Unzip, run the project and click on the button.
ftp://files.componentone.com/activereports/drops/ActiveReports_RuntimeXMLDS.rar

If you are having issues getting to it, please email activereports.support@grapecity.com and I will send it through there

ActiveReports has the rpx file format and NOT rpt.  rpt file format is from Crystal reports.